# SOAPUI, Command line execution from linux box

Tags: soapui

I want to run my soapui xml file from linux box. So what is the command to run? Or what procedure i need to follow to achieve this?

I tried below mentioned command

```
sh $/OPT/bin/testrunner.sh -s"TestSuite Name" -r -f/opt/bin/reports/ /opt/bin/soap.xml
```

But getting no such file or directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got one

```
./testrunner.sh -s "TestSuiteName" -c"TestCaseName"  -A -r -j -M -f /opt/bin -I /opt/bin/soap.xml
```